# Why am I getting an 'Error in UseMethod(arrange) in r?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, data-science

I'm writing an r program which lists sales prices for various items. I have a column called InvoiceDate, which lists date and time as follows: '12/1/2009 7:45'.  I'm trying to isolate the date only in a separate field called date, and then arrange the dates sequentially.  The code I'm using is as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

setwd("C:/Users/cshor/OneDrive/Environment/Restoration_Ecology/Udemy/Stat_Thinking_&_Data_Sci_with_R/Assignments/Sect_5")
retail_clean <- read.csv("C:/Users/cshor/OneDrive/Environment/Restoration_Ecology/Udemy/Stat_Thinking_&_Data_Sci_with_R/Data/retail_clean.csv")

retail_clean$date <- as.Date(retail_clean$InvoiceDate)#, format = "%d/%m/%Y")

   total_sales = sum(retail_clean$Quantity, na.rm=TRUE) %>% 
arrange(retail_clean$date) %>% ggplot(aes(x=date, y=total_sales)) + geom_line()
```

Initially, everything works fine, and the date field is created.  However, I get the following error for the arrange() function:

```
Error in UseMethod("arrange") :no applicable method for 'arrange' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
```

I've searched for over a week for a solution to this problem, but have found nothing that specifically addresses this issue.  I've also used '.asPosixct' instead of .asDate, with similar results.  Any help as to why the program interprets Date data as numeric, and how I can correct the problem, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try: `library(lubridate)` and then change .. to  `arrange(dmy(retail_clean$date))`

Comment: Thanks, hyena, for your comment.  I have tried to reason my way through this, to no avail.  Please let me know if this info is useful: after the line 'retail_clean$date <- as.data.frame(retail_clean$InvoiceDate, format = "%d/%m/%Y"), the class of date is 'function', and the type of date is 'closure'.

Answer (score 0):

First, the error message is not about Date time.

Let's look at the code you provided:

```
total_sales = sum(retail_clean$Quantity, na.rm=TRUE) %>% 
arrange(retail_clean$date) %>% ggplot(aes(x=date, y=total_sales)) + geom_line()
```

The result of this term `sum(retail_clean$Quantity, na.rm=TRUE)` is an integer in your case, and it is piped into the first argument of the dpyr::arrange function, which calls `UseMethod("arrange")`.

Then, the piped argument is inspected as being an object of class of `integer` and `numeric`, and `arrange` do not have a method for these classes, that is, neither `arrange.integer` nor `arrange.numeric` are defined. Hence the error msg. There is nothing wrong with you date convertion except that you do need that `format` term you commented out in the code sample.

The solution is also simple. Change `sum` to something that returns a `data.frame` or other classes that `arrange` is aware of. You can check what methods are available for `arrange`:

```
$>methods(dplyr::arrange)
[1] arrange.data.frame*
```

In this R instance, you can only put a `data.frame` object through `arrange`, but you can always define specific methods for other classes.

Looks like this is a Udemy course assignment. Maybe here you need to calculate a sum for each day or each month, whichever your assignment is asking you to do, but `sum` is definitely not the right answer.

By the way, welcome to SO!

Update:
An example

```
n <- 100
data <- data.frame(sales = runif(n), day = sample(1:30, n, replace = TRUE))
data$date_ <- paste0(data$day, "/1/2009 7:45")
head(data$date_) # This is the orignial date string
data$date <- as.Date(data$date_, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
head(data$date) # Check here to see the formated date

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data %>% 
    group_by(date) %>% 
    summarise(totalSale = sum(sales, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
    arrange(date) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = date, y = totalSale)) +
    geom_line()
```

Here is the plot

[image]

It looks fine, isn't it? The sales are all ordered by date now.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I tried both arrange.data.frame and arrange(data.frame...), and they both come back with errors.  The first says that arrange.data.frame can't be found, and the second comes back with the same tired old error.  Using lubridate also produced the original error.

Comment: I'm using RStudio 4.1.  The code is from a Udemy course, except that the instructor presumably used 3.x.  He simply ran arrange(date), and it worked fine.  I'm sick of wasting hours on these open source courses where versions change every week, and what could be done before can't be done now.  Incidentally, I also used retail_clean$date <- as.data.frame(as.Date(retail_clean$InvoiceDate)), with again the same error.

Comment: No. You do not directly use arrange.data.frame, which is not exported. Just use plain `arrange` function. I am adding a sample code example to the original answer.

Comment: I wouldn't use Udemy to learn R. Try those on edx to get started. To really understand R, you need to read the documentation page though. The thing about programming is that everything is deterministic. Things happen for a reason. Don't aimlessly try different things. Try to understand the root cause first.